# Ruby on rails. Timezones and scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, scope, timezone

I need help trying to use timezones in a scope. Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

**All dates are stored in UTC time:**

EG. A user in timezone UTC +1 posts a gig that will start at 20:00. On the gig show page, everyone will see this as 20:00, which is correct. 
My problem arises with the fact that I must 'expire' gigs, so they no longer show up in search after the `date` has passed.

Until now I have been using a scope;

```
scope :expired, -> { where('date <= ?', Time.current.to_datetime) }
```

so then `gig.expired` would show all the gigs where the `gig.date` is in the past.

The problem is that as the user is in UTC +1 timezone, for him the gig will 'expire' at 21:00, not 20:00, as it expires in UTC not UTC+1.

EDIT:

I am now saving the timezone as an attribute of the gig model upon creation.
I was already using geocoder for location, which saves coordinates.
Using the timezone gem, I can lookup the coordinates and extract the timezone, which is saved as a string to the model.

Eg. In a view, `@gig.timezone` displays `Europe/Amsterdam` (or whatever timezone was saved)

Or `<%= @gig.date.in_time_zone(@gig.timezone) %>` displays `2016-03-17 21:38:00 +0100`

My problem now, is using this with the previous scope.
If I try;

```
def self.expired
  Gig.where('date < ?', Time.now.in_time_zone("Europe/Amsterdam"))
end
```

Rails still 'expires' the gigs in UTC time.
How can I add the gigs' saved timezone, and use that in the scope?

Comment: Those scopes don't make sense to me - for example in the second one what is self supposed to be? I also thing the underlying premise - that you need to do time zone conversion in order to list expired gigs is incorrect.

Comment: Oh dear, you are correct. I've been working all day, brain is asleep, but now you've pointed it out I see that the scopes don't make sense! I will change them now. You also point out that the underlying premise is incorrect -- what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a couple of days trying to make this work I came up with a solution. If anyone can do any better I'd love to hear about it.

On gig creation I lookup the timezone with the timezone gem and save the resulting `:string` to the `timezone` attribute I created in the gig model
`Longitude` and `latitude` are available as attributes, as the gig has a location which is set in the create form;

```
timezone = Timezone.lookup(@gig.latitude, @gig.longitude)
          @gig.update_attributes(timezone: timezone)
```

Then I added another column `gigzonetime` to the gig model. I set this to the gig.date with the timezone offset subtracted.

```
 gigzonetime = @gig.date - @gig.date.in_time_zone(@gig.timezone).utc_offset
  @gig.update_attributes(gigzonetime: gigzonetime)
```

On the show and index pages I display `<%= @gig.date %>` to show the local time in which it will be displayed, and in my scope I compare to the new attribute `gigzonetime` so it expires at the correct time.

```
scope :expired, -> { where('gigzonetime <= ?', Time.current.to_datetime) }
```

This seems to be working for all timezones (future and past)
It also seems to work correctly for daylight saving time differences.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the TimeZone gem, but if you're having difficulty using it in a scope, you could consider instead simply using it in a method that returns what you want.

Fwiw, I think you're potentially making your app difficult to maintain if you're saving different times for different time zones. I could see showing the user a date that's converted to their time zone...but they should be saved in a uniform fashion. This code, if it's relying on the time zone of the current user is going to struggle. It's important to compare apples to apples.

How is date being saved? If it's being saved as UTC time just compare it to UTC time.

If you prefer to use a scope I would do something like this:

```
scope :expired, -> { where('date < ?', Date.today) }
```

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
def self.expired
  Gig.where('date < ?', Date.today)
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but I don't think you have understood me correctly. All times are saved in UTC. Eg. I live in UTC +1, and I publish a gig for 20:00. Users that look at the gig see 20:00 and that is fine, but when I need to 'expire' it, it expires at 20:00 UTC time, which is 21:00 UTC+1. I need to expire the gig at 20:00 of its own timezone.

Comment: In that case the time zone shouldn't matter at all for checking expiration. If it's saved in UTC, you should check whether it's expired in UTC. Only the user needs to see the time converted.

Comment: But if I expire it in UTC it wont expire at the correct time for a non UTC user. My timezone is UTC+1, I just made a gig with date as today at 13:20. Using 'Gig.where('date < ?', Date.today)' it expired for me at 14:20, not 13:20. This is not correct. I either need to expire in the relevant timezone, or save in the relevant timezone. I thought saving all in UTC would be less messy. Anyway, I have updated the original question so it hopefully makes more sense.